# What is first protonated aldehyde or lactone?

Tags: acid-base, carbonyl-compounds, esters

In a six membered lactone with carbaldehyde in beta position, which oxygen gets protonated first? the lactone or the aldehyde?
(Using concentrated HCl)

[image: 2-oxooxane-4-carbaldehyde]

Comment: You should assume both will be protonated and deprotonated reasonably quickly. If you're trying to get good selectivity between the two, you're out of luck.